# How to remove files of specific type in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I created .hgignore file. But forgot about `.db` files. So after `hg add` this files were added to be tracked. I found the `remove` command but can not figure out how to remove all the `.db` with a single command

Comment: Are you sure you want `remove` and not `forget`? `remove` removes the file from both the repository and the local folder, while `forget` just removes the file from the repository and leaves the local copy.

Comment: @LazyBadger: Thanks! I found the answer myself now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
hg forget "glob:**.db"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

`hg forget -I '**.db'`

Don't forget to `hg commit` that change.